# Facing issue while calling aws functions using jest

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, jestjs, nestjs

```
public async sendToSQS(data){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    AWS.config.update({...this.awsConfig});
    const sqs = new AWS.SQS();
    const params = {
      MessageBody: JSON.stringify(data),
      QueueUrl: queueUrl,
    };
    sqs.sendMessage(params, (error, data) => {
      if (error) {
        return reject(error);
      } else {
        return resolve(data.MessageId);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

And calling it from testcases like this:

```
await sqsFile.sendToSQS("test data");
```

And if an getting the error like Jest has detected the following 1 open handle potentially keeping Jest from exiting at sqs.sendMessage.
Can anybody help me out in this? I have tried all the ways and I don't want to use the --forceExit in the package.json and don't want to create a mock function.
Why i am getting this error? how can i close this open handler which is because of aws?

Comment: Could you post more of the test code, including any `beforeAll` or `beforeEach` calls, as well as the actual test assertion (`it(...)`)?

Comment: You can also try the [`--detectOpenHandles`](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--detectopenhandles) flag. As the comment above said, more information is needed to properly help you :)

Comment: @AlanFriedman In the before i am injecting the service and initiating the app.

Comment: @doublethink I have used the --detectOpenHandles in the package and because of using this I am able to know this error.

Comment: @MukeshKashyap I could take another look if you post the test code

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.
This works with the Promise.

```html
await sqs.sendMessage(params).promise();
```